# If $\int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt = 0$ then there exists non-negative functions $g, h$ with $g - h = f$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I prove or disprove this theorem?

> Let $f$ be an integrable function in $[a, b]$ such that $\int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt = 0$. Hence there exists non-negative integrable functions $g,h$ with:
>
> 1. $g - h = f$
> 2. $\int_{a}^{b} g(t) dt = \int_{a}^{b} h(t) dt$

Comment: $2$ is really a corollary of $1$.

Comment: Maybe $g=\max (f,0),h=-\min (f,0)$?

Comment: @lulu I don't think this satisfies any of the conditions.

Comment: @DHMO Really?  As you remark, the second follows from the first. And isn't the first obviously satisfied?

Comment: @lulu I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$, $x \mapsto g(x) = \max(f(x),0)$ and $h: [a,b] \to \Bbb R$, $x \mapsto h(x) = -\min(f(x),0)$, and check that $f = g-h$.

Comment: Let $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin(\pi/x)$$ and the interval $[a,b]=0,1]$. Then the integral is $\sqrt{2}\pi(1-2C(\sqrt{2}) \approx -0.2567$ wher $C(x)$ is the Fresnel integral.  But neither $\min(f(x))$ nor $\max(f(x))$ exist on this interval. So your answer does not work as a proof.

Comment: @MarkFischler please read the definitions carefully.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that same example blows this out of the water as well, since niether $g(x)$ nor $h(x)$ is integrable on $[0,1]$.  (The average value  of $g(x)$ on an interval  $[\epsilon,2\epsilon]$ is order $\frac1{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$ for $\epsilon$ near zero, so its integral is infinite.)

Comment: @MarkFischler you know that $x \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, right?